# look for a number and strings containing number should not be found

Tags: php

How should I change the code to look for a number like 22 is found, and that the elements are strings as 20 and 12 should not be found?

I want an output like this:

not found 12 - 12 found in a string, 
found 22
not found 20 - 20 found in a string

here is my code

```
$list = array("c12", 33, 6, "020b", 22, 31); 

function search($in, $what) 
{ 
foreach($in as $item) 
{ 
   if ($item === $what)
   { return "found $what"; } 
}

return "not found $what"; 
} 

echo search($list, 12); 
echo "\n"; 
echo search($list, 22); 
echo "\n"; 
echo search($list, 20);
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here. Your code seems to work fine

Comment: yea it works find. I just want it not to return found c12 when i do a search for 12 in my array.

Comment: can you give an example in your code of what you want and what doesn't work?

Comment: Seems to work fine...This is what I get: "not found 12", "found 22", "not found 20"...which is correct, right?

Comment: sorry. i wanted my code to say 12 not found and also tell me its a string for 12 not found

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
is_numeric ( $what )
```

returns true if numeric and false if string

```
    foreach($in as $item) 
    { 
       //check if numeric
       if(is_numeric ( $what )){
           if ($item === $what){
       return "found $what"; 
       } 
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need to match exact values and datatypes? Your best option is to go with the [in_array()](http://php.net/in_array) function:

```
<?php
$list = array("c12", 33, 6, "020b", 22, 31);

function search($in, $what)
{
   if(in_array($what, $in, true))
    return "found $what";

   return "not found $what";
}

echo search($list, 12);
echo "\n";
echo search($list, 22);
echo "\n";
echo search($list, 20);
echo "\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP `in_array` function does the work for you.

```
$list = array("c12", 33, 6, "020b", 22, 31);
```

`if(in_array('22', $list)
         { echo search($list, 12);}`